# cancel outgoing call with default dialer app

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have an app that becomes default dialer.

It works well on the incoming calls, answer and hang up by using `android.telecom` classes

Now what I am trying to do is, when bluetooth handset dials a number, to stop that dial, and launch whatsapp dial uri with that same number.

Any idea how to cancel the call that is being dialed trough handset?

Comment: You need to use a broadcast receiver for getting that event

Comment: and how do I cancel the call once I get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TelecomManager` class for cutting a call.

```
TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);

if (telecomManager != null) {
if(telecomManager .endCall())
Toast(mContext,"Call ended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else
Toast(mContext,"Failed to end the call",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You need the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
```

Receiver permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(OutgoingCallReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), intent.toString());
    Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing call happening!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 // cancel your call here    }
}
```

Update Manifest

```
<receiver  android:name=".OutGoingCallReceiver" 
android:exported="true"> 
<intent-filter>   
<action
android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"
android:priority="0" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Comment: thx. However, I need to cut the outgoing call that comes from bluetooth speaker, and redirect it to whatsapp. Will this listen to outgoing call?

Comment: Ah ok, I will try your solution and report back. thank you

Comment: your solution worked great on sdk 26+ but phone of my client is 23 and I need to use different solution than ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS. do you have any quick tip

Comment: There's ITelephony class for that

Comment: as this answer is excellent, I will add another question for android 6.0.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519529/how-to-cancell-outgoing-phone-call-on-android-6-0-1